# Run JavaScript when an element loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a standard HTML input that I want to run JavaScript code when it loses focus. Sadly my Google searches did not reveal how to do this.

To make it clear, I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="value" onlosefocus="alert(1);"/>
```

Answer (score 274, accepted):

How about onblur event :

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="value" onblur="alert(1);"/>
```

Comment: onBlur is triggered before the object actually lose focus.

Answer (score 72):

`onblur` is the opposite of `onfocus`.

Answer (score 38):

You want to use the [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:element.onblur) event.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="value" onblur="alert(1);"/>
```

Answer (score 25):

You're looking for the `onblur` event. Look [here](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/kayseycarvey/jss3p3.html), for more details.

Answer (score 0):

From [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp): *Made compatible with Firefox Sept, 2016*

```
<input type="text" onfocusout="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Mozilla dev. network docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event - triggers after onBlur which might be ideal in some use cases

Answer (score 0):

Just want to mention if it's **Angular**:

**Angular** doesn't take `onblur` or `onfocusout`. It **ONLY** takes **`(blur)`**:

```
  <input type="text" (blur)="myFunction()">
```