# JavaScript "Live" form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am trying to get an alert whenever a user clicks on the username or password input field and exits it without entering. However, I am able to get this to work after using "onblur" instead of "onfocus" (Thanks to Gurvinder's answer below). Now, the alert seems to work for both the fields when I click outside of the form using "onfocus". However, when I use tab key to get to password field from username field to password field, the "passwordCheck" function keeps running. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript exercises</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myForm" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td><input name="username" id="userName" type="text" onfocus="userNameCheck();"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input name="password" id ="password" type="password" onfocus="passwordCheck();"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="Button" value="Submit"></input></td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
        </form>     
        <script>

            //User name field validator - Alert a message for empty input fields
            var userNameCheck = function() {
                if(document.myForm.username.value == ""){
                    alert("User Name cannot be blank"); 

                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }

            //password field validator - Alert a message for empty input fields
            var passwordCheck = function() {
                if(document.myForm.password.value == ""){
                    alert("Password cannot be blank");

                }
                else{
                    return false;   
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't show an alert because that's really annoying. Just use the HTML5 pattern attribute to test to see if the input is empty. If it is the input will show up red to alert the user. Something like `[a-z-A-Z0-9]{1}` which checks that at least one character is present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run JavaScript when an element loses focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769135/run-javascript-when-an-element-loses-focus)

Comment: Why not just select the element of interest explicitly? document.getElementById("username") instead of document.myForm.username.length ah, maybe your onfocus is not even called... right?

Comment: Note, `<input>` element is self-closing

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091261/javascript-live-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the username input to show an alert if the user clicks on it
>   and tabs to the next field without entering any data.

If you are using focus event to check for the input validity, then unless value is pre-populated, alert will keep coming.

Use **blur** event, `onblur` instead of `onfocus`.

```
<td><input name="username" id="userName" type="text" onblur="userNameCheck();"></input></td>
```

**Demo**

```html
<body>
  <form name="myForm">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input name="username" id="userName" type="text" onblur="userNameCheck();"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input name="password" id="password" type="password"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="Button" value="Submit"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <script>
    //User name field validator - Alert a message for empty input fields
    var userNameCheck = function() {
      if (document.myForm.username.length >= 1) {
        //Nothing happens
      } else {
        alert("User Name cannot be blank");
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Gurvinder..onblur seems to fix the issue. However, I am getting repeated alerts from passwordCheck function now

Comment: You need to follow the same approach for the password as well.

Comment: Yes Gurvinder, I am using onblur for both password and username fields. For username the alert seems to work, but for password, the Alert is in infinite loop

Comment: //User name field validator - Alert a message for empty input fields
   var userNameCheck = function() {
    if(document.myForm.username.value != ""){
     //Nothing happens
    }
    else{
     alert("User Name cannot be blank");
     
    }
   }
   
   //password field validator - Alert a message for empty input fields
   var passwordCheck = function() {
    if(document.myForm.password.value != ""){
     //Nothing happens
    }
    else{
     alert("Password cannot be blank");
     return false; 
    }
   }

Comment: I have updated the new code in my question, You just need to change onfocus to onblur

Comment: @rahulsim2012 if your requirement is to not let the user move out of a field unless it is valid, then this behavior is expected since on-tab-event blur event will be invoked as well. If you don't want to hold the user on the same field at blur event, then simply remove `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own 'alert' div for more control *(and better user experience)*.

```
$("input").focus(function(){
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
        if (x == "") {
            /*alert("Password cannot be blank");*/
            $('.alert').show();
            return false;
       }
});
```

And to specify tab key scenario, try:

```
function checkTabPress(key_val) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        $('.alert').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I am looking for. But the problem is, If I use the Tab key to proceed to the next field, the alert keeps repeating.

Comment: Gotchya - updated. Hope it helps. I'd create my alert elem based on your needs.